# jQuery Validation - Validate multiple form with the same name and id

Tags: jquery, validation

I use demo on this link: http://runnable.com/UZJ24Io3XEw2AABU/how-to-validate-forms-in-jquery-for-validation

Example, I have the jQuery check validation:

```
$("#comment-reply-form").validate({

    // Specify the validation rules
    rules: {
        UserName: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        CommentContent: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 15
        },
    },

    // Specify the validation error messages
    messages: {
        UserName: {
            required: "input your name",
            minlength: "least 5 character"
        },

        CommentContent: {
            required: "input your comment",
            minlength: "least 15 character"
        },

    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

And I have multiple form in loop foreach, so how can I check specifically a "element id" in the specific form?

Comment: Ids should always be unique

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `$("#comment-reply-form").validate()`, you should use:

```
$('form').each(function(){
    $(this).validate({
    )};
)};
```

Comment: is this going to work on a form that is submitted or even for a form that is not submitted?

Comment: and how to get the submitted form id in `submitHandler` function to submit the current form?